# How to remove this for loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix

Source of the program:

```
gf <- c(2, 1, NA, 4, 5,
        4, 5, NA, 1, 2,
        3,NA, 1, NA, NA)

dim(gf) <- c(5,3)

    n = nrow(gf)
    r = ncol(gf)

    for (i in 1:r) {
        col <- gf[ ,i]
        if (FALSE %in% (c(1:n) == col[col])) {
          cat("Error (i):", i, "\n")
          break
        }
    }
    gf
```

The matrix represents a game file with a column per round. If x meets y in a game, then y meets x in the same game. Test if the redundancy in the symmetric matrix is consistent.

```
    Matrix:
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    4    3
[2,]    1    5   NA
[3,]   NA   NA    1
[4,]    4    1   NA
[5,]    5    2   NA
```

**How to eliminate the for loop and have a pure matrix formula ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to run your check by column, you can use the following:

```
apply(gf, 2, function(v) all(1:length(v) == v[v],na.rm = T))
```

such that all columns that meet your requirement can be obtained as

```
rs <- seq(r)[apply(gf, 2, function(v) all(1:length(v) == v[v],na.rm = T))]
```

Comment: When removing all() or sum(), R gives an element by element comparison. This is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I fully understood your problem, but anyway converting your code into an `apply` call is more or less straightforward.

Something like this will give you names of columns, returning TRUE if it is ok and FALSE otherwise.

```
sapply(as.data.frame(gf), function(x) sum(c(1:nrow(gf)) != x[x], na.rm=TRUE) == 0)
```

Comment: gf stands for game file indexed by player number (p) and round (r) containing the opponent of player p in round r. Within a round, the  opponent of a player's opponent is player p.